# Python 3 - verify sendto() Success

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp, sendto

I have 2 UDP responses to a destination ip, one right after the other:

```
sendsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sendsock.bind(('%s' % ip_adr, 1036))

#send first packet
ok_response = "Reception Success, more to come"
str2bytes = bytes(ok_response,'utf-8')
sendsock.sendto(str2bytes, ("%s" % phone.ip_addr, int(phone.sip_port)))

#send second packet
ok_response = "Fun data here"
str2bytes = bytes(ok_response,'utf-8')
sendsock.sendto(str2bytes, ("%s" % phone.ip_addr, int(phone.sip_port)))
```

I can see with Wireshark the second packet gets sent. But the first seems be ignored.

Unless someone can see a hiccup in my code, is there a way to do an if statement on each `sendsock.sendto()` instance, to ensure the code doesn't continue until it's acknowledged as sent?

Also, should I be closing the sendsock?

Comment: thanks Lev.  how do you apply syntax highlighting to python?

Comment: @lev added the main `python` tag to your Q, so it will highlight using that (Python 2.x Python 3.x etc... tags don't do that) - otherwise, just manually put in a `<!-- language: lang-python -->` before the code block (or just at the top of your post to make it a default)

Comment: Much clearer thanks Jon.

Comment: @coffeemonitor What you did wrong initially was indent the magic comment, so it was interpreted as part of the code. Otherwise it'd have worked just fine.

Comment: From the [socket module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto) documentation, the return of sendto is the number of bytes sent. Did you check the return value ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee with UDP that the messages will arrive synchronously or that they will even arrive at all, so it's never actually acknowledged as sent unless you send an acknowledgement response back from the receiver program. That is the tradeoff that improves the speed of UDP versus TCP.

You could, however, check the return value of `sendto` (number of bytes sent) in a while loop and not exit the while loop until the bytes sent matches the bytes of the original message or a timeout value is reached.

Also, it might be easier to use the [socketserver module](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/socketserver.html#module-socketserver) to simplify the process of handling your sockets.